# Ionic open a function from controller

Tags: controller, ionic-framework

Using a ionic sample proviede `ionic start conference sidemenu`
there is a function to open up the login **modal**

menu.html

```
<ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
Login
</ion-item>
```

**Question**
How do I open the `login()` function from a controller ? **NB**: It's not routed in the app.js so it makes things a little harder.

my attempt:
controller.js

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, ngFB, $location) {
    $location.scope('login()');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, Figured it  out.after reading documentation I had to use `$ionicModal` for modals

controller.js

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, ngFB, $ionicModal) {

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {

        scope: $scope
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
        console.log("here");
        $scope.modal.show();
    });

    $scope.closeLogin = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the login() function is located.

1. if it is located in the $rootScope, then you can call $rootScope.login()
2. If it is located in a service, then inject the service in your controller and call service.login()
3. if it is located in another controller, then put it in the rootscope or (even better) write a service.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it is right. (to help others)